# How to crop image depends on Bounding boxes

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I would like to divide image based on the bounding boxes. Image consist of column name and row, but column don't have any border so depends on gap it should divide

I am able to identify the bounding box, I am not understanding on what bases image should be cropped

```
large = cv2.imread("../forms/demo_1/crop/abc.jpg")
rgb = large

small = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
grad = cv2.morphologyEx(small, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)

_, bw = cv2.threshold(grad, 0.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 1))
connected = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(connected.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

mask = np.zeros(bw.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

for idx in range(len(contours)):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[idx])
    mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 0
    cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, idx, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    r = float(cv2.countNonZero(mask[y:y+h, x:x+w])) / (w * h)

    if r > 0.4 and w > 3 and h > 8:
        cv2.rectangle(rgb, (x, y), (x+w-1, y+h-1), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        print(x,y,x+w,y+h)

cv2.imshow('rects', rgb)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Input:
[image: Input Image]

Output:
[image: Output_1]
[image: Output_2]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you crop a rectangle from an image in OpenCV (see also this [tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#image-roi)):

```py
import cv2
large = cv2.imread("../forms/demo_1/crop/abc.jpg")

# ... your code

for idx in range(len(contours)):

    # ... your code to calculate x, y, w, g

    # example values. Use your calculated values here
    x, y, w, h = 0, 0, 60, 250

    crop = large[x:x+w, y:y+h]

    cv2.imshow('crop', crop)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Yes, but that will be hard coded. I want to crop image if the distance between two rectangle is more that 150pts.

Comment: So than you have to check the distance between rectangles and crop only based on this condition. Something like so: `for idx in range(len(contours)-1):
    if abs(xs[idx] - xs[idx+1]) > 150:
        crop = large[x:x+w, y:y+h]`

Comment: By `xs` I mean a list of all the calculated x values of your `contours`. `xs = [cv2.boundingRect(contours[idx])[0] for idx in range(len(contours))]`